# Custom sorting in ordered container

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, standard-library

I've got an ordered container (usually `std::vector`) with objects, say

1. `Banana`
2. `Apple`
3. `Peach`

and above custom order. Now the objects go through some processing, might have been removed from the container and reinserted, resulting in a new ordered container.

I have stored the order (`Banana` -> **1**, `Apple` -> **2**, `Peach` -> **3**) separately and would like to re-establish that particular custom order in the new ordered container.

The objects are already present at this time (i.e. I cannot simply insert in the desired order).

So rather than swapping excessively with some naive algorithm on my own I was wondering if there's some algorithm in the standard library I could employ in a cunning way..?

Comment: Why not leave the objects in the container and copy out of the container?  vector returns a reference that you can work on.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `std::sort(fruits.begin(), fruits.end(), [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) { return rank[a] < rank[b]; });` where `rank` is `std::map<std::string, int>` holding your string-to-rank mapping?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Cheers - that did the job.. could have thought of that myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pretty much what Igor wrote does the job..

```
std::sort(fruits.begin(), fruits.end(), 
          [&](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) 
          { return rank[a] < rank[b]; } );
```

where rank is `std::map<std::string, int>` holding the string-to-rank mapping

Answer (score 1):

std::sort is in the standard library AND it's pretty cunning! It can sort by the default < operator (which you could override for your fruit) or you can supply a comparator that's external to your class' implementation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort

Comment: (Oh, Igor beat me to it!)

Comment: I think the question is, what should be in that operator